# Rails - Texts don't fit my layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, layout

Ok, I guess this is a pretty easy solution question. Everything that is shown by a `text_area` don't fit my layout. I want it to fit perfect, break the lines and stuff like that, but it just don't go. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing

```
:wrap => :hard
```

so your html looks like this:

```
<textarea cols="20" rows="5" wrap="hard">
```

Comment: Really thanks, it worked. Do you know how can I make it better, and if I put like "Hello <breakline> How are you?" it displays the message not like "Hello How are you?"

Comment: Well works only if the text is separated by spaces, if it is all together like "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" it breaks again ;/

Comment: you mean changing line break to html <br>? In rails there is simple_format("some text") method for that

Comment: there is no hack in html for "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" ;) but if you expect words that long you should think of larger textarea :)

Comment: Ok I understood. And How can I use this method?

Comment: in your view write <%= simple_format(@object.some_property) %>

Comment: Here is where the text goes displayed in the view: `<span class="content"><%= message.content %></span></br>`. What I should do and there I configure the text?

Comment: <span class="content"><%= simple_format(message.content) %></span></br>